# Is it possible to prioritize which folders get synced first when using Ubuntu One?

Tags: ubuntu-one, sync

I face the problem that u1 syncs my files to a given order. I'd like to change that order. Consider that: On a week end I work and I may also copy the content of my photo SD card onto my notebook. The next time I boot my work computer, I might be sitting there and waiting for some hours until U1 synced/downloaded all the photos to my workstation and the files I need for work are the last in the '--waiting' list.

I don't mind if Ubuntu One is a slow downloader, I would be just happy if I could define that all files in a certain folder (and all of it subfolders) always need to be downloaded first.

I'm aware that there was once the possibility to move some files to the beginning of the sync list. But that was a very clumsy way with providing the folder id etc. and in the current version of u1 I can't even find it any more.

Any suggestions on how to prioritize always the same folder?

Comment: no ideas here??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer is no, there is no way to prioritize the order in which files are synchronized. There is however, a workaround for situations like yours.

Instead of having all files under the `~/Ubuntu One` folder, you can have different files under different folders within your home directory, which are each individually synchronized with Ubuntu One. You can then choose to only have certain folders synchronized to certain machines, and you can disable and enable the folders being synchronized on any one machine, in the Ubuntu One control panel application. Thus you could disable `~/Photos` from being synchronized, until after `~/Documents` has finished synchronizing, for example.